# How to use java library in Gradle Build Script?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I need to use Apache Commons in my Gradle script, so where do I need to add the dependency to make it available to it?

(I don´t need it in my Android Project, but only in the gradle script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the dependencies in `buildscript` section as follows:

```
buildscript {
    .
    .
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.commons:commons-*:<version>'
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Adding `repositories` block would be also useful.