# Call Kotlin method from Gradle Task

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to build a utility Gradle task, that will read some code (using reflection) in a specific package and generate a report (some json structure for example).

This code reader is in a specific package, and I am looking to call this function somehow from tasks.register in gradle. Has anyone done something like this? Or has idea how-to?

Comment: Are you saying you have a library you want to use in the Gradle build script?

Comment: You could say that. I am authoring a small library, that will read code in a module/package and I want to run it from gradle task

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843091/how-to-use-java-library-in-gradle-build-script

Comment: Otherwise, you might need to create a "proper" plugin. Though if this is local to one Gradle project, then that plugin can be written in `buildSrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Only a Gradle Java plugin could ever get access to it; the default directory is `buildSrc`.
Alternatively, build a JAR and then execute `java` with an `Exec` task, if it has to be a task.
It doesn't make much difference, because the plugin would have to register task anyway.
In any case, you'll not run Kotlin or Java unless transpiling or compiling it to byte-code.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I got it to work using this in my gradle:
application {
    mainClass.set("some.cool.packagePath.ReportGenerator")
}

And the mentioned ^ module references the module I want to scan.